# Unable to link custom font via @font-face on GitHub Page

Tags: css, github, font-face

I am trying to use a custom web font on a GitHub page using `@font-face` in my `CSS`. I created a folder in the repository and uploaded the `.woff`-file of the font I want to use. However, I seem to be unable to properly link the font. Below you'll find the very basic HTML and CSS I am working with.

In my GitHub page ( `[username].github.io` ) it is possible to simply link a stylesheet, since it is sitting in a folder in the same directory as `index.html`:

[image: Directory of my GitHub Page]

Now, why do I seem to be unable to link a `.woff`-file also sitting in a folder in the same directory?:

[image: Location of the .woff-file linked in the CSS]

I tried to do so by linking to the font via `@font-face` and using `Assets/AkzidenzGrotesk-Regular.woff` as the `url`. Yet, the site refuses to use the font and falls back on Times, as specified in the `CSS`.

Can someone help my out and explain to me, why this is happening? How do I have to link the font-file in order to use it on the site?

My Index file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/basic.css">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>

    <h1>Personal HTML-Projcet</h1>
    <p>Personal web design project, hosted via GitHub-Pages.</p>

        <div class="grotesk">

            <p>This is a test, using Akzidenz Grotesk as a webfont.</p>

        </div>

</body>

</html>
```

And the respective CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: AkzidenzGroteskRegular;
    src: url(/Assets/AkzidenzGrotesk-Regular.woff);
}


body {

    background-color: white;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;

    }

h1 {

    color: black;

}

p {

    color: black;

}

.grotesk {

    font-family: 'AkzidenzGroteskRegular', 'Times';

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you refresh your cache, because everything I see on [j0hnga1t.github.io](https://j0hnga1t.github.io/) shows that the  [Berthold Akzidenz-Grotesk Regular](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/berthold/akzidenz-grotesk-be/regular/) font is used.

[image]